# iPad detail settings page like popup viewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

The first thing i would like to clarify is that i'm not talking about the splitview controller. I want a pop up with a navigation controller similar to the one you get when you tap the Keyboard>>Languages or Mail>>New Account.

[image: Popup style navigation Controller]

Now this is not a popover controller, any standard framework available for this? Maybe i'm missing the obvious. The good things about this is that it has navigation controller and hence  the view resizes to fit subsequent tableview lengths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a popover. It's a `modalView` with presentation style `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`

Check this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

For more presentation styles refer [ModalPresentationStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationStyle)

> **Presentation Styles**
>
> Presentation styles available when presenting view controllers.
>
> typedef enum {
>
> UIModalPresentationFullScreen = 0,
>
> UIModalPresentationPageSheet,
>
> UIModalPresentationFormSheet,
>
> UIModalPresentationCurrentContext
>
> } UIModalPresentationStyle;
>
> *Constants*
>
> **UIModalPresentationFullScreen**
>
> The presented view covers the screen, taking into account the value of the wantsFullScreenLayout property.
>
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>
> Declared in UIViewController.h.
>
> **UIModalPresentationPageSheet**
>
> The height of the presented view is set to the height of the screen and the view’s width is set to the width of the screen in a
>   portrait orientation. Any uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent the
>   user from interacting with them. (In portrait orientations, this
>   option is essentially the same as UIModalPresentationFullScreen.)
>
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>
> Declared in UIViewController.h.
>
> **UIModalPresentationFormSheet**
>
> The width and height of the presented view are smaller than those of the screen and the view is centered onscreen. If the device is in a
>   landscape orientation and the keyboard is visible, the position of the
>   view is adjusted upward so the view remains visible. All uncovered
>   areas are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with them.
>
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>
> Declared in UIViewController.h.
>
> **UIModalPresentationCurrentContext**
>
> The view is presented using the same style as its parent view controller.
>
> When presenting a view controller in a popover, this presentation style is supported only if the transition style is
>   >
>   **UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical**.
>   Attempting to use a different
>   transition style triggers an exception. However, you may use other
>   transition styles (except the partial curl transition) if the parent
>   view controller is not in a popover.
>
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>
> Declared in UIViewController.h.